# Setting parent to child process group with setpgid fails

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I'm trying to change the pgrp of the processes to that of the child's so i can `setsid` on the parent process. The only thing is I keep getting an `EPERM` error code. Both processes have the same session group, according to htop.

I'm basing this off of this [blog post](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/), so I can change which terminal output gets directed to.

```
void sig_exit(int signum)
{
    _Exit(0);
}

pid_t change_process_group()
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    if ((child_pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failed while attaching to term");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        pid_t parent = getppid();
        setpgid(0, getpid());

        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_exit); // wait till parent tells child to exit

        //sleep(5);
        //kill(parent, SIGUSR2);
        pause();
        printf("Shouldn't reach this\n");
    }

    //sleep(5);
    //signal(SIGUSR2, sig_wait);
    //pause();
    int parent_pid = getpid();
    int code = setpgid(parent_pid, child_pid); // need child process group
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    setsid();

    return  child_pid;
}

main()
{
   pid_t child = change_process_group();

   kill(child, SIGUSR1);
}
```

The commented out lines were from me thinking the processes might not be executing in the correct order, but those don't appear to fix the problem.
How may I correctly use `setpgid` to change the pgrp of the parent process to the child's?

Answer (score 1):

This is a race condition and it works if you uncomment the `sleep(5)` line in the parent. When you call `setpgid(parent_pid, child_pid)`, the `child_pid` *process group* must exist. It isn't enough that there exists a process with the PID `child_pid`: `setpgid` needs an existing process group unless the process is putting itself into its own group. If `setpgid(parent_pid, child_pid)` in the parent runs after `setpgid(0, getpid())` in the child, it works.

Sleeping is both inefficient and fragile, so instead of that the parent should wait for a notification from the child. Signals are fragile because there aren't many different signals and they could come from anywhere. A good way to communicate between related processes is a pipe. Since all you need here is a one-time notification, you can set up a pipe and read from it in the parent (with the write end closed in the parent). The parent will wait until the child writes to the pipe or closes it. In the child, just close the write end of the pipe when you've finished the preparations. The parent's `read` call (or `select` if you need to do other things at the same time) will return.

Proof-of-concept code:

```
pid_t change_process_group()
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_ready_pipe[2];
    if (pipe(child_ready_pipe) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((child_pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failed while attaching to term");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        close(child_ready_pipe[0]);
        sleep(1); // mimic slow start of the child
        if (setpgid(0, 0))
            perror("child setpgid to create group");
        close(child_ready_pipe[1]);

        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_exit); // wait till parent tells child to exit
        pause();
        printf("Shouldn't reach this\n");
    }

    close(child_ready_pipe[1]);
    int parent_pid = getpid();
    char ignored;
    read(child_ready_pipe[0], &ignored, 1);
    close(child_ready_pipe[0]);
    if (setpgid(parent_pid, child_pid) < 0) // need child process group
        perror("parent setpgid");
    if (setsid() < 0)
        perror("parent setsid");

    return  child_pid;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense with the race condition. The only issue I'm having still is if the debugger  (gdb) is attached, I receive errors for parent setpgid, and setsid. Is that since gdb is the parent process?

Comment: @ZeroPhase There are restrictions on `setpgid` on a session leader. Check the man page. Running the process in gdb might change whether the process starts out as a session leader.